# Pointers and reference run in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, reference

Ok i have some problems understanding how pointers work on C and why this is not working. 
I create a structure with 3 variables inside of it, and i want to initialize it inside of the function "LeerFicher". As far as I understand, I am passing the memory direction to the function, so i would be able to initialize the members of the structure from inside of the function right? CodeBlock is giving me this error:
error: request for member 'duracion' in something not a structure or union|
any help??

```
typedef struct canciones{
   int duracion;
   int popularidad;
   int valor;
}canciones;

int main()
{
   canciones arraySolucion[20];
   leerFichero("canciones.txt", &arraySolucion);
}

   void leerFichero(char *nombre_fichero, canciones *solucion[])
{

   char linea[500]; // Para guardar la linea de cada fichero
   char *token;     // Para cada token de cada linea
   int i, e;

   //Abrimos el fichero
   FILE *fp = fopen(nombre_fichero,"r");

   // Recorremos cada linea del fichero
   while(fgets(linea,500,fp)!=NULL)
   {
       for(i=0; i<20; i++)
       {
           token = strtok(linea,";"); // Separamos cada linea por ","
           while(token != NULL)
           {
               for(e=0; e<5; e++)
               {
                   printf("%s\n",token);
                   switch(e)
                   {
                   case 0:
                       **solucion[i].duracion=atoi(token);**//error is here
                       break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared an array of structures ,like

```
canciones arraySolucion[20];
```

and are passing it to a function like the expression

```
&arraySolucion
```

that is like a pointer to the array.

Thus the expression has the type `canciones ( * )[20]`.

However the corresponding parameter of the function has the type `canciones *solucion[]` that is the same as the type `canciones **solucion`.

There is no implicit conversion from the type of the argument and of the type of the parameter.

Moreover the function shall be declared before its usage in main.

In fact the function can be declared like

```
void leerFichero( const char *nombre_fichero, canciones solucion[], size_t n );
```

and called like

```
leerFichero("canciones.txt", arraySolucion, 20 );
```

In this case within the function you could write

```
   for(i=0; i < n; i++)
   {
       token = strtok(linea,";"); // Separamos cada linea por ","
       while(token != NULL)
       {
           for(e=0; e<5; e++)
           {
               printf("%s\n",token);
               switch(e)
               {
               case 0:
                   solucion[i].duracion=atoi(token);
                   break;
```

Also it is unclear what the magic number `5` in the inner loop means.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct canciones{
   int duracion;
   int popularidad;
   int valor;
}canciones;

void leerFichero( const char *nombre_fichero, canciones solucion[], size_t n );

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 20 };
    canciones arraySolucion[N];
    leerFichero( "canciones.txt", arraySolucion, N );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%zu: %d, %d, %d\n", 
                i,
                arraySolucion[i].duracion, 
                arraySolucion[i].popularidad, 
                arraySolucion[i].valor );
    }        
}

void leerFichero( const char *nombre_fichero, canciones solucion[], size_t n )
{
    puts( nombre_fichero );
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        solucion[i].duracion    = ( int )i;
        solucion[i].popularidad = ( int )i;
        solucion[i].valor       = ( int )i;
    }
}
```

Its output is

```
canciones.txt
0: 0, 0, 0
1: 1, 1, 1
2: 2, 2, 2
3: 3, 3, 3
4: 4, 4, 4
5: 5, 5, 5
6: 6, 6, 6
7: 7, 7, 7
8: 8, 8, 8
9: 9, 9, 9
10: 10, 10, 10
11: 11, 11, 11
12: 12, 12, 12
13: 13, 13, 13
14: 14, 14, 14
15: 15, 15, 15
16: 16, 16, 16
17: 17, 17, 17
18: 18, 18, 18
19: 19, 19, 19
```

Comment: Yeah, but doing that i am not initializing the structure "arraySolucion". When i try to print his values in the main, it only prints his memory directions not the value of the members. I want to change the value of the structure into the function "LeerFichero" and then use it outside of it.

Comment: @javierromero I showed you how this can be done. What you are doing after the function call I do not know.